# Custom teasers and show summary checkbox

Tags: 7, nodes

The function generating teasers in D6 does not make nice teasers.  At the same time I do not want to bother my users to set teasers themselves, I would rather get rid of the whole system.

Anyway, I tried writing a little helper module which went through the published nodes and tried to correct teasers that were too short or too long.

My problem:

1. Between the `node_load()` and a `node_save()`, what parts should I care about, just place a `<!--break-->` in `$node->body` or adjust `$node->teaser`?
2. I had the problem after adjusting `$node->teaser` and deleting the break; the "Show summary in full view" checkbox was unchecked when manually editing this node.  Which variable is controlling this checkbox and how do I set it?
3. If I wanted to implement some teaser-corrections via `hook_nodeapi()`, which event should I hook to, when I do not want to patch the node core module and interfere with its `node_teaser()` function?

I know there are a couple of modules around, that store teaser data in separate CCK fields.  I would like to avoid this if possible.  (and yes, I want to have a proper value for the teaser variable and not just manipulate the output via views etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set `$node->teaser` to the value you want to use as teaser. That is what [node_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_submit/6), the function indirectly called from [node_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/6), does.
- [node_body_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_body_field/6), the function that add the form fields for the node body, contains the following code:

```
// Check if we need to restore the teaser at the beginning of the body.
  $include = !isset($node->teaser) || ($node->teaser == substr($node->body, 0, strlen($node->teaser)));

// …

$form['teaser_include'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox', 
  '#title' => t('Show summary in full view'), 
  '#default_value' => $include, 
  '#prefix' => '<div class="teaser-checkbox">', 
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

The checkbox is not selected if

1. the teaser is set, or
2. the teaser is not the initial part of the body

- I would use `hook_nodeapi('presave')`, which is invoked before the node is saved, but before `hook_nodeapi('insert')` or `hook_nodeapi('update')`.

To notice that, if the problem is the length of the teaser, [node_teaser()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_teaser/6), uses the value of the "teaser_length" Drupal variable as length if the teaser. I am not using Drupal 6, but if I remember well, there should be a setting page that allow to change the value of that variable. If the value of the variable is not modified from a setting page, then you can set it in settings.php, or from a custom module.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Somehow I was looking at the wrong place, I was aware of teaser_include from some debug output but must have overlooked the quoted code.  My problem resulted because the teaser I inserted had stripped tags and thus differed from the substr of body.